# Trouble Converting to 64 Bit in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently trying to archive and publish my app to the app store, but I have encountered an issue.

"This bundle is invalid. Apps that include arm64 architecture cannot have MinimumOSVersion set to less than '5.1.1'. More information about 64-bit support for iOS is available at "64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch" at developer.apple.com"

So, I do as I'm told and I go to view apple's instructions on how to convert to 64 bit.

Step 3) Update your project settings to support iOS 5.1.1 or later.

I'm completely lost on how to do that. I also don't know if I've already done that. My Deployment Target is 8.4 and my Base SDK is 8.4, however I don't know how to view the status of the iOS of my project settings.

Step 4) Change the Architectures build setting in your project to "Standard Architectures (including 64-bit)."

My current architecture is: Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

I tried to change it to the one Apple wants, but there is no option for it.

[image]

How do I fix this/these issues so that I may deploy my app to the app store?

Comment: It sounds to me like you've done it right. But if you're in doubt, what I would do is make a new project in Xcode 6.4 and move all your stuff (code, storyboard, resources) into it. That way you have something up to date and guaranteed to be valid from the outset.

Comment: For some reason it believes that my MinimumOSVersion is less than 5.1.1.  How do I see that setting and change it?

Comment: I don't know why that is, but it won't believe that if you do what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you use or not 32bit SDK or 32bit Third party Libraries like Metaio. and please use latest  SDK for Facebook or GooglePlus.